# AFNetworking + CocoaSPDY sending requests, not getting response

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, spdy

I'm trying to setup SPDY over AFNetworking but I'm having trouble knowing why am I getting timeouts.

I've already checked my server at [SPDY check](http://spdycheck.org/) and everything looks alright.

I put this line of code in my `initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url` method

```
NSString *origin = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:443",kAPIClientBaseURLString];
[SPDYURLConnectionProtocol registerOrigin:origin];
```

I'm getting debug logs that appear to be alright

```
2013-12-23 15:26:37.889 Proj[42859:70b] SPDY [INFO] register origin: <SPDYOrigin: 0x19156fa0>
2013-12-23 15:26:37.890 Proj[42859:420f] SPDY [DEBUG] origin registered: <SPDYOrigin: 0x19156fa0>
2013-12-23 15:26:37.892 Proj[42859:441b] SPDY [INFO] start loading https://api.proj.mx:443/2/ursers/launching_info?param1=1&param2=2
```

Then after some seconds of waiting i get

```
2013-12-23 15:28:07.994 Proj[42859:441b] SPDY [INFO] stop loading https://api.proj.mx:443/2/dr/drs?param1=1
2013-12-23 15:28:07.996 Proj[42859:441b] SPDY [WARNING] session connection error: Error Domain=SPDYSocketErrorDomain Code=6 "Unexpected end of stream." UserInfo=0x13e52710 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected end of stream.}
```

And if I print the error, it displays as a timeout.

If I remove the SPDY integration (the 2 lines I wrote above) it all goes as it should.

I don't really know whats going on, would appreciate any help and comments.

Thanks.

*I changed urls to avoid privacy and security issues.*

Comment: any good news on this?

Answer (score 2):

The CocoaSPDY library requires a server that either speaks SPDY over a dedicated port or that is capable of dynamically switching to a SPDY pipeline when it receives a SETTINGS frame over a newly-established connection.

As far as I know, GFE doesn't currently do either of those things meaning that unfortunately, at present, the CocoaSPDY library won't be supported at Google API endpoints.

Do you control your own server? If so, it's quite possible that it's by default relying on NPN to establish the protocol, and you'll instead want to configure it to simply speak SPDY when your application connects to it.

Comment: Hey Mike, I checked [here](http://spdycheck.org/) and [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/#Go_SPDY) so I think it actually supports SPDY. I think the problem is somewhere inside the framework or maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I dont know what. THanks for your time

Comment: Hi @RoHiguera - I can't know for sure without knowing more about the server you're attempting to connect to, but my first guess is still that NPN is being used to negotiate the protocol.

This is the current standard mechanism a server would automatically use to decide if a browser supports SPDY while establishing a TLS connection. The CocoaSPDY library skips this step (because Apple's Secure Transport doesn't currently support NPN), and simply starts sending SPDY over the wire. You will need to use a server configured to support that.

Answer (score 1):

Does your server support SPDY?

Try setting a breakpoint in the `socket:willDisconnectWithError:` delegate method.  You can inspect `[socket unreadData]` to see any unread data.

If this doesn't give you any helpful information, try implementing (and logging) [the other delegate methods](https://github.com/twitter/CocoaSPDY/blob/master/SPDY/SPDYSocket.h).

Comment: I'll try those delegate methods and let you know how it goes. Thanks!